# How to view kivy application logs in pc

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I'm beginner in python and also in kivy (maybe kivymd). I've hardly created an app (at last). It's work fine on pc. Then I've converted it to apk with `BUILDOZER` in google colab. I also full fill the `buildozer.spec` file. But when I install and run it on my android (vivo y93), It shows a default kivy loading screen, and with in 2 sec, It crashed. So I'm badly need of a kivy log viewer. I searched on google about it. but there is mac and linux softwares. Is there any logviewer software you know well or any build in kivy function to save the log file in a separate folder? I can't give you screenshot at this time, But you can get `main.py` [here](https://pastebin.com/dl/CaMsq3wJ), if you need so.

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the ".buildozer" folder in your project folder, then edit your "buildozer.spec" file and add the requirements:

```
requirements = kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.1,python3,pyjnius,plyer,requests,urllib3,chardet,idna,pip,Image,PIL,watchdog
```

And then compile your app once again.
That's what I use most of the times for my apps, also the issue maybe the "MDNavigationLayout" in the kv lang section, but you will have to review both, the requirements and the MDNavigationLayout